# If I have a 500ohm resistor in series with 3V motor, with an input voltage of 5V, will it work?

Tags: resistors, motor

Here is a picture of the circuit I wish to make: Resistor, motor, switch, buzzer

[image: Resistor, motor, switch, buzzer]

Comment: It depends how much the motor takes current. Do you know the current?

Comment: It'll "work" but, whether it does what you want is impossible to say.

Comment: Consider say 5 diodes in series instead to drop ~2 V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if the motor draws

$$
I = \frac{2V}{500\Omega} = 4mA
$$

For currents above that the motor will get less than 3 V, for currents less than that the motor will get more than 3 V. The motor current will vary depending on how mch load is put on it, so with a resistor the voltage across it will not be constant.

3 V hobby motors typically draw 50 mA to 500 mA, so there's quite a range. Some are rated for a range of voltages and will work fine at 5 V, they'll just have a higher unloaded speed than at 3 V. You need to look at the specifications for your particular motor.

If you want a consistent 3 V, a better solution would be to use an LDO or switching regulator. An LDO will waste more power, \$2 V\cdot I_{motor}\$, basically 2/5 of the power from your supply will be wasted as heat, so ~ 60% efficiency (a resistor would waste the same amount). A switching regulator will probably be at least 80% efficiency which would be important if you're running from batteries. With either type of regulator there's a minimum input voltage so if using batteries you have to take into account that their voltage will drop over time and may go below the regulator minimum.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem!

Comment: @gcsestudent6784 What did you end up doing?

Comment: 3/5 V would be the efficiency of a linear dropper, so 60 %, not 40.

Comment: @winny Oops. Fixed.